# 2GFSK digital filter bandwidth calculation

Tags: software-defined-radio, modes, software-development, components

I'm working on a [S2LP from ST](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/s2-lp.pdf) and I am configuring the RX digital filter.
I need to calculate the bandwidth of the signal which has 2GFSK modulation.

Do you think the code below is correct for estimating the signal bandwidth for a given XO and a given datarate ?

```
    uint8_t xo_ppm = 10;
    xRadioInit.lFrequencyBase = 869400000;
    xRadioInit.lDatarate = 80000;
    xRadioInit.lFreqDev = xRadioInit.lDatarate / 2;

    double drift = (xo_ppm / 1e6) * xRadioInit.lFrequencyBase;
    xRadioInit.lBandwidth = xRadioInit.lDatarate + 2 * xRadioInit.lFreqDev + 2 * uint32_t(drift);
```

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

Comment: Hello Victor, and welcome to this site! :-)